# How can I build application on CoreFX that was built from source

Tags: c#, .net, dnx, dnvm, coreclr

I try to build application with dotnet core that was built from github repos.

What I do:

1. Clone/download CoreFX: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx.git - OK
2. Try to build it. [Instructions are here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/building/windows-instructions.md) - ОК
3. Install DNVM/DNX. Built and run hello world app [Instructions are here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/install/get-dotnetcore-dnx-windows.md) - ОК
4. Start new branch on local git corefx repo. Change CoreFX. Build/test as in "2". - OK
5. Write some simple C# console application (only CS file) that I want to test in "vanilla" CoreFX and "custom" CoreFX.

If I understand correctly, I need to do the following:

1. Install cores built from source to dnvm/dnx (to be able to switch between them)
2. Correct project.json to use some libs from CoreFX
3. Create VS project with some settings to be able to debug my app

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm curious why you're targeting CoreFx straight from Github instead of the supported .NET Framework releases.

Comment: See step 4. Some classes was slightly changed by me. I try to compare behavior of github version (without my modifications) and modified libs. It is not production code.

Comment: Have you found an answer? I'm wondering to know it.